# Mysql query to find all rows that have the same values as another row

Tags: mysql, sql

My database contains rows that generally look like:

```
PersonItem
__________
id
personId
itemId

╔════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ PERSONID ║ ITEMID ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  2 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  3 ║      123 ║    555 ║
║  4 ║      444 ║    456 ║
║  5 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  6 ║      333 ║    555 ║
║  7 ║      444 ║    456 ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

I need to find all the actual records where the PersonId and the ItemId column match some other record in the database for those two columns....

```
| 1  |   123    |   456
| 2  |   123    |   456
| 5  |   123    |   456

| 4  |   444    |   456
| 7  |   444    |   456
```

How can I go about getting these results?

Comment: You mean both match, or at least one match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do joins to get around with duplicate records.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PersonID, ItemID, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY PersonID, ItemID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON  a.PersonID = b.PersonID AND
                a.ItemID = b.ItemID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10930/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ PERSONID ║ ITEMID ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  2 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  5 ║      123 ║    456 ║
║  4 ║      444 ║    456 ║
║  7 ║      444 ║    456 ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want and takes the least amount of time to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: do you have an index on both columns? `INDEX(PersonID, ItemID)` ? it will make more faster.

Comment: I do have an index on both columns, and you're query runs just fine.  50ms on about 500k records.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT P1.*
FROM PersonItem P1
INNER JOIN PersonItem P2 ON P2.ID <> P1.ID
AND P2.PersonId = P1.PersonId
AND P2.ItemId =   P1.ItemId
```

Comment: This is the neatest answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find examples where the pair of personid/itemid appear more than once.  In MySQL you can do this with a `where` clause and subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              group by personid, itemid
              having count(*) > 1 and
                     t2.personid = t.personid and t2.itemid = t.itemid
             )
```

The above is standard SQL.  MySQL also supports the multi-column `in` statement.  So this can be written as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.personid, t.itemid) in (select personid, itemid
                                 from t
                                 group by personid, itemid
                                 having count(*) > 1
                                )
```

And alternative that I like, based on Eugene's answer but more efficient, is:

```
SELECT t.personid, t.ItemId, GROUP_CONCAT(t.ID)
FROM t
GROUP BY t.personid, t.ItemId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

It does away with any joins, if you don't mind getting the ids as a list rather than as separate rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This does work, does what I need.  For my table this is the slowest of the options though.  Both of these take between 5 and 10 seconds where the other answers presented take 50ms.

Comment: @kasdega . . . All the answers will run faster if you have an index on `personid, itemid`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is a systematic problem: In this case a subquery will execute per-row, while a join will not - see the execution plans!

Comment: @EugenRieck . . . It is systematic, as you say.  However, the "execute once per row" becomes an index lookup with an appropriate index, making it equivalent to the join in terms of performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the execution part of the query - but don't forget, that running the subquery takes more than just the execution part! E.g. a new query plan is calculated for every instance of the subquery. This is counterintuitive but true.

Comment: Concerning your variation of my answer: I am not persuaded, that this is more efficient: It will create a temp table with all groups, as the `HAVING` can only be applied, after the first loop finishes. The join will only accept those rows, that have at least one double. If you have many rows, but few duplicates, the having is guaranteed to be very inefficient.

Comment: @EugenRieck . . . That is interesting.  I didn't realize the execution plan would actually be re-created.  Has this improved along with the other optimizations in 5.6?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have seen this in all our production MySQLs, so it must already be present in at least late 5.5. It does make sense, though!

Comment: @GordonLinoff love the revision (2nd answer) !!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p1.ID), p1.personid, p1.ItemId
FROM PersonItem AS p1
INNER JOIN PersonItem AS p2  ON 
    p1.ID<>p2.ID
    AND p1.personid=p2.personid
    AND p1.ItemId=p2.ItemId
GROUP BY p1.personid, p1.ItemId
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why should I? It is an INNER JOIN and I have ruled out the self-join via `p1.ID<>p2.ID`