# MySQL - Find rows that have same column but match certain ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some sample data that looks something like this.

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ PERSONID ║ ITEMID ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      123 ║    1   ║
║  2 ║      123 ║    2   ║
║  3 ║      123 ║    3   ║
║  4 ║      444 ║    1   ║
║  5 ║      123 ║    4   ║
║  6 ║      444 ║    2   ║
║  7 ║      444 ║    3   ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

I will typically parse the data into something like this:

```
PERSONID - 123
    ITEMID - 1
    ITEMID - 2
    ITEMID - 3
    ITEMID - 4


PERSONID - 444
    ITEMID - 1
    ITEMID - 2
    ITEMID - 3
```

Say I am given a few `ITEMID` values: `[1, 2, 3]`, exactly like the `PERSONID - 444` group. How can I write a query to check if there is a group of rows with the same `PERSONID` value and contains the exact same `ITEMID` values (no more no less)

Comment: what code are you using for this

Comment: I'm using MySQL for the database but I haven't written the query yet, not sure where to start

Comment: ok i will start working on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to find all rows that have the same values as another row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803592/mysql-query-to-find-all-rows-that-have-the-same-values-as-another-row)

Comment: I looked at that but it's a bit different because it's not just checking for same values in one column, we have to have an exact match for the other column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `group by` with `count` and `not exists`

```
select personid
from Table1 t
where not exists ( select 1 from Table1  t1 
                   where t1.itemid not in (1,2,3)
                   and t1.personid = t.personid
                  )
group by personid
having count(*) =3
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the PERSONIDs exactly having same ITEMID values use this:

Say the table name is `PERSON_ITEM`

```
SELECT P.PERSONID 
 FROM PERSON_ITEM P
 WHERE 
   P.ITEMID  IN (1, 2, 3)
  GROUP BY P.PERSONID
  HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT P.ITEMID) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for a simple text-based match:

```
select PERSONID
from mytable
group by PERSONID
having group_concat(ITEMID order by ITEMID) = '1,2,3'
```

Note that the ids you seek must be specified in order.