# what is the best method to Identify which pairs of rows have identical Products, Customers and Measures, and overlapping date ranges?

Tags: sql, database

[image of sample question where i have to identify duplicate rows then make date ranges not overlap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOKkl.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to find all rows that have the same values as another row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803592/mysql-query-to-find-all-rows-that-have-the-same-values-as-another-row)

Comment: If not a duplicate, sample data and expected results are always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping for row 1, 2 is represented as:

```
rows 1 and 2 are overlap , like this:
               20130101  |--------------------| 20130401
                20130301      |----------------------| 20131231
```

You can use T-Sql language in MS SQL Server:

```
select t1a.id , t1.id second_id, 
t1.valid_from_day , t1.valid_to_day  , 
t1a.valid_from_day second_valid_from_day , 
t1a.valid_to_day   second_valid_to_day
from t1 t1a
cross apply
(
 select * from t1 
 where t1.product = t1a.product 
 and  t1.customer = t1a.customer
 and  t1.measure = t1a.measure
 and t1.id <> t1a.id
 and t1.valid_from_day >= t1a.valid_from_day  -- overlap
 and t1.valid_to_day >= t1a.valid_to_day
) t1
```

The results of the query is:

```
id  second_id   valid_from_day  valid_to_day    second_valid_from_day   second_valid_to_day
1           2           2013-03-01  2013-12-31  2013-01-01  2013-04-01
4           5           2013-03-01  2014-04-01  2013-01-01  2013-04-01
9           10          2014-04-01  2015-01-01  2013-03-01  2013-12-31
```

so The pairs identical are:

```
pair 1,2
pair 4,5
pair 9,10
```