# How to find pairs of data in SQL Server with specific parameter with liberal variation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I show table and what I need from SQL Server table with specific parameter with liberal variation from parameter column if parameter pass from variable.

I don't know how can I achieve this result.

Filter Parameter:

```
ParameterFilterB    -           
ParameterFilterC    -           
ParameterFilterD    -           
ParameterFilterE    -   B
```

Table:

```
A   B   C   D   E
------------------
1   A   A   A   A
2   A   A   A   B
3   A   B   A   C
4   A   B   A   D
```

Result :

```
A   B   C   D   E
------------------
1   A   A   A   A
2   A   A   A   B
3   A   B   A   C
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your logic a little bit more?

Comment: I have multiple parameter, if they pass then check else not on particular column with +/- 1 value.

Comment: Still not clear to me. Maybe include a few more examples?

Comment: If we pass ParameterFilterC  with value B  in my example  then we get all records, I have product inventory with sequential data, 
so we need to find product which nearly same parameter with +/- 1 in particular column,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803592/mysql-query-to-find-all-rows-that-have-the-same-values-as-another-row

this is near about my result, but in this variation not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql) and [CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) functions.

You may also want to check for minimum/maximum allowed characters e.g. what happens when someone enters A or Z

For `ParameterFilterB` the code would look like this:

```
DECLARE @ParameterFilterBMin CHAR( 1 ), @ParameterFilterBMax CHAR( 1 )

-- Set first search letter
SET @ParameterFilterBMin =
    CASE
        -- Handle edge case
        WHEN @ParameterFilterB = 'A' THEN 'A'
        -- Get previous letter
        ELSE CHAR( ASCII( @ParameterFilterB ) - 1 )
    END

-- Get last search letter
SET @ParameterFilterBMax =
    CASE
        -- Handle edge case
        WHEN @ParameterFilterB = 'Z' THEN 'Z'
        -- Get next letter
        ELSE CHAR( ASCII( @ParameterFilterB ) + 1 )
    END

-- Find matching values
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE colB BETWEEN @ParameterFilterBMin AND @ParameterFilterBMax
    -- AND/OR colC BETWEEN @ParameterFilterCMin AND @ParameterFilterCMax
    -- etc.
```

You should be able to replicate this for the other parameters

Comment: I also need paired, so how can i apply dynamic grouping like this field?

Comment: @HirenJasani - to use multiple filters, add them to the `WHERE` clause. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I want to know that ,

if i pass one parameter then grouping apply only on one field, 

if i pass two parameter then grouping apply on two field,

how can i achieve that? Because i also need to apply paired count, means if user select 2 then i give them only that record which is more than 1.

Comment: @HirenJasani - 1. I do not understand half of what you are trying to say. 2. Make some effort in modifying the code I gave you to suite your needs.